# What is the upper limit on number of TcpClient instances in .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, tcpclient, windows-server-2012

We have an application that sequentially opens TCP connections using `TcpClient`on a separate `Task`, in a nutshell, one `Task` has one `TcpClient` instance. 
There are 56 such `Tasks`. Each `TcpClient` polls a TCP server and each polling has 7 TCP Send/Receive.

We found that the 57th `Task` `TcpClient` does not get connected.

So, is there an upper limit imposed over only certain TCP sockets are handled by Windows Server 2012 with .NET 4.5 ?

Any pointer/guidance appreciated!

Comment: Are all these TcpClient's connecting to the same server?  Then you need to use a telephone.  The answer will be "no" however.

Comment: @HansPassant : The TCP servers are all individual servers (basically ModbusTCP slave devices) and others are Gateways (Ethernet to Serial), we open maximum of 7 client connections to a gateway.

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a circus, what could possible go wrong?  I'll randomly guess that TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning could be useful.